# Calling Process.WaitForExit() in button clicked event is blocking program

Tags: c#, buttonclick, waitforexit

I have written same app using Windows Forms to run process after button was pushed and read its standard output. When I call method "test()" in button1_Click() my program is blocking. But when I call "test()" in "Form1" constructor everything work as expected. Where is problem?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DISMassistant
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/?";

        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void test()
        {
            process1.Start();

            process1.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process1.BeginErrorReadLine();

            process1.WaitForExit();
            process1.CancelOutputRead();
            process1.CancelErrorRead();
            process1.Close();
        }

        private void process1_OutputDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) return;

            richTextBox1.Text += e.Data + "\n";
        }

        private void process1_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) return;

            richTextBox1.Text += e.Data + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use WaitForExit(), favor the Process.Exited event.  Or don't wait at all, the process1 object is not usable anymore anyway so cleaning up isn't that useful.  Do wonder a bit if you actually intended that.

Comment: This is how the WaitForExit method works. It halts the current thread until it detects the remote process has exited.

Comment: But it is blocking nothing when I call it this way:
`code
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/?";
           
            test();
        }
`

Comment: You could print out the name of the current thread for both invocations and see if they differ. Most probably your constructor is executed by a different thread than your button_click handler, which is invoked by the ui thread.

Comment: Where do you assign the `OutputDataReceived` event?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing all of the missing parts in your sample code, there's no issue (beyond, of course, that you wouldn't want to `WaitForExit` in a GUI application):

```
// Warning - The code below is WRONG! Awful even, since it will _appear_ to work in some cases.
void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    Process process1 = new Process();
    Button button1;
    RichTextBox richTextBox1;

    public Form1()
    {
        button1 = new Button { Text = "Run" };
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        Controls.Add(button1);

        richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox { Left = 100 };
        Controls.Add(richTextBox1);

        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/?";
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test();
    }

    public void test()
    {
        process1.Start();

        process1.OutputDataReceived += process1_OutputDataReceived;
        process1.ErrorDataReceived += process1_ErrorDataReceived;

        process1.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process1.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process1.WaitForExit();
        process1.CancelOutputRead();
        process1.CancelErrorRead();
        process1.Close();
    }

    private void process1_OutputDataReceived(object sender, 
                                             System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) return;

        richTextBox1.Text += e.Data + "\n";
    }

    private void process1_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, 
                                            System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)) return;

        richTextBox1.Text += e.Data + "\n";
    }
}
```

However, this is still something you do not want to do. GUI controls shouldn't be accessed from a different thread than they were created on. I'm not getting a problem in my test application, but even if it works, this is just disaster waiting to happen.

It so happens that `RichTextBox` has a bit weird handling of the `Text` property. If the handle isn't created yet, `Text` only changes a single field in the class. It doesn't do any multi-threaded access checking or anything. Now, when the handle actually gets created, the value from this field is applied to the text of the control for real - on the correct thread.

This is probably why you're seeing your weird behaviour. In the form constructor, the handle isn't created yet. The access from a background thread is still a bad idea, but it doesn't actually break anything, most of the time (you may lose some of the process output). When the form is shown, the handles are created, and the text box shows the "correct" output.

When the form *is* already created (and shown), this changes. On a single-threaded apartment thread, you're expected to handle multi-threading yourself. You're not supposed to access a control from a different thread - and most controls will call you out on it and throw an exception. For whatever reason, `RichTextBox` isn't (always) that kind of control. So as it happens, on STA, the code happens to work - not reliably or safely, but it doesn't hang, and it doesn't crash.

But your UI thread seems to be in a multi-threaded apartment. And in MTA, when you try to assign text to the `RichTextBox` (with a created handle), the message is marshalled to the UI thread. But your UI thread is busy waiting for the process to exit! Thus, you hang.

How do you solve this?

1. Never access GUI controls from a different thread than the one they were created on. Marshal the call explicitly (e.g. using `Invoke`), and you'll get reliable and consistent behaviour.
2. Do not block the UI thread. `Process` has an `Exited` even that allows you to react to the process exiting in an asynchronous way.